# Why does this code give a StackOverflowError

Tags: java, methods

I'm writing a method which is calculating the formula (x+y)/z if every variable's value is greater than zero. If they're smaller than zero the console should print "0".

My code looks like this:

```
package arrayTest;

public class berechne {

    public static int berechneZahlen (int x, int y, int z) { //method
        int ergebnis=0; 
        if (berechneZahlen(x, y, z) > 0) {
             ergebnis = (x+y)/z; //ergebnis = result
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("0");
        }
        return ergebnis;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print(berechneZahlen(2, 3, 6));

    }
}
```

Now, in the editor I don't get any error. Everything seems fine. But when I'm compiling it, it gives me this error a dozen times:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at arrayTest.berechne.berechneZahlen(berechne.java:7)
    at arrayTest.berechne.berechneZahlen(berechne.java:7)
    at arrayTest.berechne.berechneZahlen(berechne.java:7)
```

I couldn't figure it out why the code isn't working properly.

Comment: unfortunately you are using recursion

Comment: You are recursively calling `berechneZahlen()` method and running out of memory.

Comment: The error happens at run time, not compile time.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/), will help you in Naming Conventions.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling your function recursively without termination point, so it cause `StackOverFlowError`

```
if (berechneZahlen(x, y, z) > 0)
```

Instead, introduce your code to check for `x, y, x > 0` to match your requirement:

> if every variable's value is greater than zero. If they're smaller than zero the console should print "0".

```
if (x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0) {
    //bla bla
} else {
    //print 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method calls itself recursively. Try this:

```
public static int berechneZahlen (int x, int y, int z) { //method
  int ergebnis=0; 
  if (z>0 && (x+y) > 0) {
    ergebnis = (x+y)/z; //ergebnis = result
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("0");
  }
  return ergebnis;
}
```

Comment: One-liner: `public static int berechneZahlen (int x, int y, int z) { return (x>0 && y>0 && z>0) ? ((x+y)/z) : 0`}

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things wrong but also some things that can be improved.

what causes the error is that you are not checking if x,y,z is bigger than 0 but you are checking if `berechneZahlen` of those numbers is bigger than 0 which causes it to be called recursivly.

Furthermore in the case of one of them being 0 you are printing "0" in the method but you are also printing the result of `berechneZahlen` in your main function, resulting in "0" being printed twice, so you probably only want to return 0 in that case and not print it in the function itself.

Finally, I would also remove your `ergebnis` variable. It's not wrong but it's not necessary. you could simply just return the result.

This would then be your final result

```
public static int berechneZahlen (int x, int y, int z) {
    if (x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0) {
        return (x+y)/z;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But it can even be made shorter using a ternary operation like this

```
public static int berechneZahlen (int x, int y, int z) {
    return (x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0) ? (x+y)/z : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `StackoverflowError` is caused by a *[recursive call](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/)*. That means the method `berechneZahlen()` is calling itself. In that call it is calling itself again and in that next call it is calling itself again and so on..

```
public static int berechneZahlen (int x, int y, int z) {
    ... 
    if (berechneZahlen(x, y, z) > 0) { // (fatal) recursive call here
         ...
    }
```

Each single call allocates space on your computers memory until the memory is completely filled up with data and there is no more space left. In this moment the program execution breaks down, because it needs to allocate more space to work, but it can't allocate more.

Here is a working solution for you, where the recursion has been removed:

```
public class berechne {

    public static int berechneZahlen (int x, int y, int z) {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0) {
            return 0; // return 0, if one of the numbers is below zero
        }
        return (x+y)/z; // return normal calculated result
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(berechneZahlen(2, 3, 6));
    }
}
```